# Powerautomate unable to connect to a AWS Postgres RDS instance

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, power-automate

I am trying to connect a Microsoft Power automate online flow to a AWS RDS Postgres instance. However the connection does not working either using a encrypted option or without. The postgres DB instance is a public facing DB instance.
Using the encrypted option I get the following message -
[image]

Without the encrypted option I get the following message -

[image]

Can anyone figure out what the issue could be? Thanks!

Comment: We are encountering the same issue. Have you attempted to connect to the PostgreSQL database using a different application? We successfully connected with DBEAVER using the same credentials. However, when attempting to do so with Power Automate, it didn't work. We came across a message in other forums suggesting that we should avoid using '@' in the password, but even after making this change, the issue persists.